# Good beautiful silky, long hair in Jannah?

Tags: halal-haram, jannah

What if I wanted beautiful, astounding, silky, long luxurious hair. Could I get this in Jannah? Could God grant me this wish? I have an afro, a teeny weeny afro. Why couldn't God create in my head beautiful long hair. I want to look like Kate Middleton in Jannah, is this possible? Could God grant me these desires?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum,
Jannah was created for us and Insha Allah we will get all that we desire. Allah can grant you anything you want.

Buraydah ibn al-Hasib reported: A man asked the Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, “O Messenger of Allah, will there be camels in Paradise?” The Prophet said, “If Allah admits you into Paradise, you will have therein whatever your soul desires and pleases your eyes.”

May Allah grant you Jannah...